# Simple click-to-move script not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code:

```
public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Vector3 _startLocation = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 _currentLocation = Vector3.zero;
    private Vector3 _endLocation = Vector3.zero;
    private bool _isMoving = false;
    private float _distanceToTravel;

    private float _startTime;

    public float Speed = 1.0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {

            Debug.Log("Left mouse button clicked");

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
                {
                    _startLocation = transform.position;
                    _endLocation = hit.point;
                    _isMoving = true;
                    _startTime = Time.time;
                    _distanceToTravel = Vector3.Distance(_startLocation, _endLocation);

                    Debug.Log(string.Format("Ground has been hit: Start: {0}, End: {1}", _startLocation.ToString(), _endLocation.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }

        if (_isMoving)
           Move();
    }

    void Move()
    {
        float timeElapsed = (Time.time - _startTime) * Speed;
        float t = timeElapsed / _distanceToTravel;

        _currentLocation = Vector3.Lerp(_startLocation, _endLocation, t);

        transform.Translate(_currentLocation);

        if (_currentLocation == _endLocation)
        {
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Destination reached ({0})", _endLocation.ToString()));

            _isMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I read the documentation on the `Vector3.Lerp` function, as well as the `Physics.Raycast` function, and ended up with this code.

The debug console confirms that the Ground has been hit, but my capsule starts moving upwards in the Y direction and never stops!

I'm still very new to Unity and game development in general, so I'm still learning, but any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think I just realized that I'm using `deltaTime` when I should in fact be keeping time since the movement started since it's a linear function...

Comment: I've edited my code to use the `Lerp` function correctly (instead of using `deltaTime`, but should I still be using that somewhere...?), so now my capsule moves in the x and y axes, but it's still moving upwards in the Z axis infinitely.

Comment: Correction: moving infinitely in the positive-Y axis, not Z. I'm used to the coordinates Blender uses...

Comment: So what is your goal to do? Is the Capsule have to move within ground? then you have to stop capsule when it is out of ground.

Comment: The Ground in this case is just a flat plane, my goal is to click on the plane and have the capsule move to the location where I clicked. Eventually the capsule will be replaced with a character model.

Answer (score 1):

it is moving in the Y because you use transform.Translate.

transform.Translate is moving it, so if you did transform.Translate(0, 0, 10)
it would move in the z, and if you did transform.Translate(0, 10, 10)
it will move in the y and z direction.

So to fix this i will show you 2 ways:

1) Using Vector3.Lerp:

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_startLocation, _endLocation, t);
```

2) Using MoveTowards:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _endLocation, Speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

In the first Vector3.Lerp is used, and i see you use it too

```
_currentLocation = Vector3.Lerp(_startLocation, _endLocation, t);
```

So you could do either this:

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_startLocation, _endLocation, t);
```

or this

```
transform.position = _currentLocation;
```

Both will do the same because you assigned _currentLocation to

```
Vector3.Lerp(_startLocation, _endLocation, t);
```

And you can read about MoveTowards here
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html

Comment: And one more thing reinitialize ' _startLocation ',  to move the capsule from  last position where it leave

Comment: Yeah, but i thought he wanted the same behaviour as he has now, so i only looked at replacing the transform.Translate :-) But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Comments line You will understand what I had edited to bring the Solution. 
It works well for me

```
void Start()
{
    _startLocation = transform.position; // Changed Here to Initialize once  
}
    void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {         
        Debug.Log("Left mouse button clicked");
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Ground"))
            {   
                print(hit.point);
                //**Here you mentioned _StartLocation = transform.position
                //this instantly changes the starting point Every time so
                //if SP changes then totally changed in Translation.*** 
                _endLocation= hit.point;
                _isMoving = true;
                _startTime = Time.time;
                _distanceToTravel = Vector3.Distance(_startLocation, _endLocation);
            }
        }
    }
    if (_isMoving)
    {
         Move();
    }

}

void Move()
{
    float timeElapsed = (Time.time - _startTime) * Speed;
    float t = timeElapsed / _distanceToTravel;

    _currentLocation = Vector3.Lerp(_startLocation, _endLocation, t);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_startLocation, _endLocation, t);
    _startLocation = _endLocation;
                 //*** This line is for Next Mouse
                 //click. So every next click StartPoint is Current Click
                //EndPoint***
    if (_currentLocation == _endLocation)
    {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("Destination reached ({0})", _endLocation.ToString()));
        _isMoving = false;
    }
}
}
```